# ListView (using CustomListAdapter) and AsyncTask not updating UI

Tags: web-services, listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter, ksoap2

Currently i am trying to allow my listview to be updating inside asynctask.
Getting the data is not a problem, the problem lies at updating the main thread's ui.
I am using a webservice method to get the data, just in case you want to know.

I tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); , listView.refreshDrawableState(); & listView.requestLayout();
individually and together none of which worked.

I have also tried the runOnUiThread function in both doingInbackground and onPostExecute of my asynctask none of which also work.

I have been through the forum and tried almost all things and somehow i'm still having the problem while others have progressed with a solution.

Initially, the first item is shown from the data i retrieved from the xml datastore, but all the other items are not showing.
But if i change the orientation to landscape the last two rows are not shown immediately in the view, if you scroll down to the last items in the list the values are there and then the two top rows are not shown.
When you scroll up, the 2nd row in the list is now shown.

Here is how the app looks initially:

http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/1035/androidimage.png

Here is some snippets of my main thread called NewListView.

```
package com.nico.gg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewListView extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;
    ProgressDialog PostingDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        PostingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        PostingDialog.setTitle("Updating Rates");
        PostingDialog.setMessage("Retrieving Rates, Please wait...");
        PostingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        PostingDialog.setCancelable(true);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row,
                rowItems));
        new DownloadXmlTask().execute();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public class DownloadXmlTask extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Rate>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Rate> doInBackground(Void... value) {
            ArrayList<Rate> val = loadXmlFromNetwork();
            return val;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            PostingDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Rate> val) {
            super.onPostExecute(val);
            PostingDialog.dismiss();
            CustomListViewAdapter adapter = (CustomListViewAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
            try {

                if (val.size() > 1) {

                    // for(Rate y: x){
                    for (int i = 0; i < val.size(); i++) {

                        RowItem item = new RowItem(R.drawable.rihanna,
                                String.valueOf(val.get(i).getGasRate()), val
                                        .get(i).getDateModified()
                                        .toLocaleString());
                        adapter.add(item);
                    }

                    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Toast.makeText(NewListView.this, "Rates Updated",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Rates Updated Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Rate> loadXmlFromNetwork() {

        return new CallSoap().MostRecentPetrojamRate();
    }
}
```

This is my custom Adapter Class

```
package com.nico.gg;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView txtRateName;
        TextView txtDatePosted;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(row == null){
            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtRateName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.gastype);
            holder.txtDatePosted = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
            holder.txtRateName.setText(rowItem.getRateName());
            holder.txtDatePosted.setText(rowItem.getDatePosted());
            holder.image.setImageResource(rowItem.getRateImgId());
        }
        return row;
    }



}
```

Thanks for stopping by and trying to help...
I await you comments, towards my problem.

Comment: i fixed it seems as i though i should remove the closing bracket from the else statement in my custom adapter to placed it after:
holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();